# Set up plugin for jsonschema_typed in mypy

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I wanted to use `jsonschema_typed` for type checked with mypy.
I installed `jsonschema_typed` from pip:
`pip install jsonschema-typed`

I have all dependencies (jsonschema, mypy).

And tried example:

```
from jsonschema_typed.types import JSONSchema

data: JSONSchema['path/to/schema.json'] = dict(title='baz')
data['description'] = 'there is no description'  # TypedDict "FooSchema" has no key 'description'
data['awesome'] = 42
data['awesome'] = None  # Argument 2 has incompatible type "None"; expected "Union[int, float]"
```

But nothing happend.
I tried to write plugin into setup.cfg file:

```
plugins = jsonschema_typed.plugin.JSONSchemaPlugin.get_type_analyze_hook
```

But mypy shows that error:

```
setup.cfg:10:1: error: Error importing plugin 'jsonschema_typed.plugin.JSONSchemaPlugin.get_type_analyze_hook'
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Use either the full name of plugin module: `plugins = jsonschema_typed.plugin`, or path to module file: `plugins = /path/to/lib/python/site-packages/jsonschema_typed/plugin.py`